# jQuery changes the source code correctly, but not the rendered page result. (with jsFiddle proof)

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

Here is my jQuery:

```
$("object").each(function(){
    video_url  = $(this).find('embed').attr('src');
    new_video_url = video_url+"&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&theme=light";
    $(this).find('embed').attr('src', new_video_url);
    $(this).find('param:eq(0)').val(new_video_url);
    $(this).find('embed').before('<param name="autoplay" value="1"><param name="showinfo" value="1"><param name="modestbranding" value="1"><param name="hd" value="1"><param name="color" value="white"><param name="autohide" value="1">');
});
```

Here is what the code looked like before the jQuery:

```
<object width="500" height="371">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ISeQBRUa8xQ&amp;rel=0&amp;egm=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;fs=1">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <embed 
        src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ISeQBRUa8xQ&amp;rel=0&amp;egm=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;fs=1" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        width="500" 
        height="371" 
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        mode="transparent"
    >
</object>
```

Here is what it looks like after the jquery has been executed.

```
<object width="500" height="371">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ISeQBRUa8xQ&rel=0&egm=0&showinfo=0&fs=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&theme=light">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="autoplay" value="1">
    <param name="showinfo" value="1">
    <param name="modestbranding" value="1">
    <param name="hd" value="1">
    <param name="color" value="white">
    <param name="autohide" value="1">
    <embed 
        src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ISeQBRUa8xQ&rel=0&egm=0&showinfo=0&fs=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&theme=light" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        width="500" 
        height="371" 
        allowfullscreen="true" 
        wmode="transparent"
        >
</object>
```

Even though the HTML code has successfully changed, the rendering of the page does not show the updated code.

Here is a jsFiddle proving the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4kQYy/4/

If you inspect the second youtube video in your inspector, you'll see that it actually gets the code injected 100% correctly, yet the page render does not reflect the update. How can that be? Surely what you see in source code is what you see on screen? Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a flash expert but my logic says, that what you are trying to do can not work. What happens in my opinion are the following steps:

1. You initialize a flash instance
2. On initialization the flash movie gets the parameters and acts apropriatly
3. Afterwards you change the params, which have no effect on the flash movie anymore

What you could do is either move the whole flash instantiation process to javascript. That means you generate the whole object tag. Or you detach the object tag, make your customizations and reinsert it again. I updated the code in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/4kQYy/10/)

```
$("#foobar").each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent(),
        object = $(this).detach()

    video_url  = object.find('embed').attr('src');
    new_video_url = video_url+"&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&theme=light";
    object.find('embed').attr('src', new_video_url);
    object.find('param:eq(0)').val(new_video_url);
    object.find('embed').before('<param name="autoplay" value="1"><param name="showinfo" value="1"><param name="modestbranding" value="1"><param name="hd" value="1"><param name="color" value="white"><param name="autohide" value="1">');
    parent.append(object);
});
```

I know that this does not work in every condition especially, if the parent has more than one child, but it should give you a general idea.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks a stack! Makes sense and it's nice and clean.